# Are they correct to say "She's got 2 butterfly hairpins in / on her hair" and "She's got a hairband in / on her hair"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

Look at this picture

[image]

Do we say "**She's got 2 butterfly hairpins *IN / ON* her hair**"?

---

Look at this picture

[image]

Do we say "**She's got a hairband *IN / ON* her hair**"?

Comment: If they are HAIRpins, you don't need to specify a location. Same goes for HAIRbands.

Comment: I agree."She has hairpins on".

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty, some native speakers say "hairpins in her hair"

Comment: @Tom OK, Tom, then you've answered your own question. Do you find any instances of "hairpins on her hair"? You would usually use "in" with "hair", and "on" with "head".

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty, the hairpin or hairband is on her head but in her hair. That is what they suggested to me.